# Plot in VBA Using Variable

Tags: excel, vba

So here is the code that I am working with:

```
c = Application.Match("Test", Range("F1:F130"), 0)        
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'" &  "!$B$104:$N$104"
```

So similar to the plot I would want to be able to say because c+4 = some integer which is not always 104.

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'" &  "!$B$(c+3):$N$(c+3)"
```

I have tried using doing something like:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'" & "!$B$" & " (c+3):$N$" & " (c+3) "
```

This did not work... obviously, but I am very new to VBA and the syntax, so any help is appreciated. 
Here is the function for shtname as well:

```
    Function shtname() As String
    shtname = ActiveSheet.Name
    End Function
```

Comment: try **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'!$B$" & (c+3) & ":$N$" & (c+3)**

Comment: @MutjayLee it is a row number

Comment: @MutjayLee worked like a charm, submit it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even variable, if it's between "" then it becomes string.

---

for example let's say your shtname is "Sheet1"

On your last try line

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'" & "!$B$" & " (c+3):$N$" & " (c+3) "
```

Basically, you are setting XValues as

**='Sheet1'!$B$(c+3):$n$(c+3)**

Try

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & shtname & "'!$B$" & (c+3) & ":$N$" & (c+3)
```